# How do I make the option bar to disappear if I have option?

Tags: php, wordpress, types

I will have 2 options for some playlist when the users click "listen now" . So the options are Spotify link or Youtube link. For some playlist, I will not have 2 options to choose, so I will have one options which is Soundcloud link for example. Right now, it showing 2 options when I click "listen now" but how do I make the "listen now" button for one options too?

my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fboyf8qo/4/) code (without php code)

For 1 options, I don't want "option-bar" to show up, I want the "listen now" button link to soundcloud link for example. That means when I have option 1, I want the code look like this, so the users is not choosing.

```
   <button class="btn-wrap">
     <a class="btn-wrap" target="_blank" href="#">
       <div class="btn">listen now</div>
    </a>
  </button>
```

---

This is 2 options , spotify link and youtube link. Because I don't always have spotify and youtube link. Sometime I will have one option for the playlist.

```
<?php

        $args  = array('post_type' => 'music-playlist');
        $query = new WP_Query($args);

        $cntr = 0;

        while( $query -> have_posts() ) : $query -> the_post(); $cntr++; ?>

    <section class="row-wrap">
        <div class="row-inner music-wrapper">

            <?php if ($cntr % 2 == 1) { ?>

            <div class="poster-wrap">
                <img class="poster" src="<?php echo(types_render_field('artwork', array('raw' => true) )); ?>"> 
            </div>

            <div class="poster-content">
                <h1><?php echo(types_render_field('playlist-name', array('raw' => true) )); ?></h1>
                <p><?php echo(types_render_field('description', array('raw' => true) )); ?></p>

                <button class="btn-wrap">
                    <div class="btn">listen now</div>
                </button>

                <div class="option-bar">
                    <a target="_blank" href="<?php echo(types_render_field('spotify-url', array('raw' => true) )); ?>">Spotify</a> or <a target="_blank" href="<?php echo(types_render_field('youtube-url', array('raw' => true) )); ?>">Youtube</a>
                </div>
            </div>


            <?php } else { ?>

            <div class="poster-content">
                <h1><?php echo(types_render_field('playlist-name', array('raw' => true) )); ?></h1>
                <p><?php echo(types_render_field('description', array('raw' => true) )); ?></p>

                <button class="btn-wrap">
                    <div class="btn">listen now</div>
                </button>

                <div class="option-bar">
                    <a target="_blank" href="<?php echo(types_render_field('spotify-url', array('raw' => true) )); ?>">Spotify</a> or <a target="_blank" href="<?php echo(types_render_field('youtube-url', array('raw' => true) )); ?>">Youtube</a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="poster-wrap">
                <img class="poster" src="<?php echo(types_render_field('artwork', array('raw' => true) )); ?>"> 
            </div>
            <?php } ?>

        </div>
    </section>
```